# Convert 20141013T155544.673-04/0 to DateTime C#

Tags: c#

I need to convert

```
20141013T155544.673-04/0
```

To a DateTime type.

Presently I am manually parsing the string out

```
 //20130605T154727.683-04/0
                //20130806T143808.018-04
                //var a = new DateTime();
                var year = segmentDate[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[2].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[3].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var month = segmentDate[4].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[5].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var day = segmentDate[6].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[7].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                //s[8] == "T";
                var hours = segmentDate[9].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[10].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var minutes = segmentDate[11].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[12].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var seconds = segmentDate[13].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + segmentDate[14].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string milliseconds = null;
                if (segmentDate.Contains("."))
                    milliseconds = segmentDate.Split('.')[1].Split('-')[0];
                if (milliseconds != null && milliseconds.Contains((" ")))
                {
                    milliseconds = milliseconds.Split(' ')[0];
                }
                var offset = Convert.ToInt32(segmentDate.Split('-')[1].Split('/')[0]);
                var a = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month),
                    Convert.ToInt32(day), Convert.ToInt32(hours), Convert.ToInt32(minutes),
                    Convert.ToInt32(seconds), Convert.ToInt32((milliseconds ?? "0"))).AddHours(offset);
```

But that is a bad idea - and I cannot believe that this format isnt specified somewhere (that I have been able to find).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update**

```
4 digit year 
2 digit month
2 digit day
T - denotes start of the time portion
2 digit hour
2 digit minute
2 digit second
. - denotes start of MS
3 digit ms
TZ offset (-04)
/0 I believe is offset minutes
```

**Update2**

So I have been playing with TryParseExact and ParseExact - and cannot come up with a format string that will pull this into a DateTime/DateTimeOffset type.

I also consulted with the supplier of this value and they also have a manual process to parse it out, like I posted already.

I cannot accept that this is the only way to achieve the desired result, and as such, will continue to play with it.

But if anyone else has suggestions, they are welcome here.

Comment: Did you try using `DateTime.TryParseExact`?

Comment: Do you know what the part after .673 is supposed to be?

Comment: @DanielA.White - Trying it now - lenniep - Its the offset

Comment: Try using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx to make your own datetime format, and then try `DateTime.TryParseExact` or `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to explain?

Comment: Yes - I could've just went straight to TryParseExact - my hope was that this seemingly standard format would have a ready made solution just sitting out there that I haven't been able to find. Using TryParseExact assumes the format will never change. I dont know that to be true.

Comment: how do you expect to parse a format that isn't consistent? If this is a standard format, it should always stay the same.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I just dont have control over it. Using TryParseExact with an array of format strings would probably be best

Comment: You could make it easier for you if you took the parts of the datetime you are sure about (for instance the first 8 characters, the date) and use DateTime.ParseExact to parse those. At least you wouldn't have to parse everything manually.

Comment: Can you explain what that `-04/0` at the end is supposed to be? I first thought it might be a timezone info - but those would be `-04:00` or something like that....

Comment: @marc_s It is time zone - at least the -04 part is. I believe the /0 indicates no minutes but I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
string s = "20141013T155544.673-04/0";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss.fffzz/0",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the `/0` represents minutes (and can be 0 or 30 then you could do a little manipulation to convert that to a "standard" time zone indicator:

```
string s = "20141013T155544.673-04/30";
string s2 = s.Replace("/0",":00").Replace("/30",":30");
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s2,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss.fffzzz",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```